# Сочетание времен в главном и придаточном

Tags: времена

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, как правильно: "Он знал, что Тим был прав." или "Он знал, что Тим прав." Равнозначны ли оба варианта по смыслу, если можно и так и так? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском языке нет императивных требований на согласование времен придаточного и основного предложений в изъявительном наклонении. Поэтому в принципе возможны любые сочетания прошедшего, настоящего и будущего времени. Некоторые типы придаточных, однако, налагают собственные грамматико-смысловые требования на время основного предложения. Так, невозможно, например, "Когда я смотрю в окно, на улице шел дождь".
В рассматриваемом примере таких ограничений нет, поэтому **оба варианта возможны**.

В отношении же эквивалентности значений сказать что-либо трудно. Фразы типа "Он знал, что я изучал грамматику",  "Он знал, что я изучаю грамматику", "Он знал, что я буду изучать грамматику" оставляют открытым вопрос о времени изучения как относительно момента, когда "он знал", так и по отношению к настоящему времени. Тем более понятие "(был) прав" не имеет четкой фиксации во времени. Поэтому самое правильное -  исходить из контекста. **Скорее всего "Он знал, что Тим прав" означает, что Тим прав на момент, когда "он знал", а "был прав" - к более раннему моменту, но всё это, особенно последнее, очень субъективно.**

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта по смыслу равнозначны. В 1-м предложении глагол-связка "был" составного именного сказуемого присутствует, а во 2-м предложении — отсутствует.

Comment: Добавлю, по моему мнению (точнее, по моим наблюдениям), визуальное наличие глагола-связки характерно для письменной речи, отсутствие — для разговорной.

Answer (score 3):

Сказуемое БЫЛ ПРАВ благодаря глагольной связке БЫЛ выражает  временный признак. Был прав в какой-то конкретной ситуации, например. Сказуемое ПРАВ указывает на постоянный признак. Прав в принципе. Так что решайте сами, что Вы хотите сказать о Тиме. Оба варианта приемлемы, но я бы выбрала второй.